# How to target site search users with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, search, google-analytics, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I'm a bit confused that how could I target/create trigger for site search users?
I want to run custom Javascript for these users.

I would like to believe that there is already something that would tell that this user used site search?

Or do I need to create a custom variable and set it on dataLayer and create a custom trigger that checks a aforementioned custom variable?

EDIT: So, in other words I would like to **tag** the users as search user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a segment filtering Users Visits with Site Search and apply segment wherever you need to.
[image: segment screenshot]

Comment: Isn't this a segment in Google Analytics? I need to get the Tag Manager to know that this is a site search users and to trigger code for it...